# Why does Visual Studio not resolve my CSS class names?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio

Whenever I am working in Visual Studio I always found that it will not resolve the css class names in my html.  The CSS Class names will appear with the green squiggly line in Visual Studio but then the page will render fine when viewing it in the browser.   So I know the css file is referenced correctly in my master page but Visual Studio is just failing to resolve it.  Also the Design View will not show any of the css styles either.

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to answer this without seeing an example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this post by Jeff King about getting Visual Studio to be able to find the javascript file with the intellisense: [JScript IntelliSense FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx).

In particular read point #4, third bullet:

> Site-Relative Paths - These are paths
>   of the form "/folder/file", and is
>   calculated from the base of your site
>   (http://site/application/folder/file).
>   This approach is supported by ASP.NET
>   Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC.  However,
>   it is not supported by Visual Studio. 
>   The reason is because Visual Studio
>   does not always know the final
>   deployed location of your site and
>   thus the path resolution cannot be
>   guaranteed.  Given that quite we've
>   seen few folks are using site-relative
>   paths, we could consider making an
>   assumption just resolving this type of
>   path to the root of the project. 
>   Given the risk that you may think your
>   site is working when it's really not,
>   I wanted to see how many people were
>   supportive of this.

Notice the “[Site-Relative Paths are] NOT supported by Visual Studio”.  I always use site relative paths for my javascript and css files so the solution to get Visual Studio to find your javascript files is the same solution to get Visual Studio to find your css files:

```
<link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% if (false) {%>
    <link href="../../content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

And now Visual Studio can find the CSS file and validate my CSS Class names exist (and Design View looks so much better too).

Posted on my blog here:
[Why does Visual Studio not resolve my CSS class names?](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/06/07/why-does-visual-studio-not-resolve-my-css-class-names.aspx)

-Jeff

Answer (score 2):

I just saw an answer to this, so I thought I'd share it.
You can get VS2008 to recognize your CSS file by going to the View/Manage Styles toolbar and adding your CSS file that way.  When I did it I saw my CSS file in the Manage Styles list but it had a warning icon because VS couldn't see it for some reason.  I deleted and re-added it, and now VS is finding my styles (no green error squiggle) and Intellisense is working.  Much relieved!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to just close the project and open it again? It might be that it's just a bit slow, or you're using some sort of path to the stylesheet (generated on basis of other data or whatever) that can't be read directly by VS.

Never experienced the same (VS08).